# hide scrollbars when transitioning on android using jqm

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

im using Phonegap and jQuery mobile. ive got a standard page with tabs at the bottom as buttons. when i transition to a page the scrollbars appear at the bottom as the page slides in. can i hide the scrollbars when the page is sliding in?

Comment: I am using this: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/ with slide transition.